# Problema com Solicitação AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo um sistema de login de usuários.
Quando o Usuário faz o submit do form a solicitação AJAX não está funcionando e a página muda para o login.php

JS

```
$("form").submit(function() {

    if ($("#login_username").value() != "" && $("#login_password").value() != "") {

        $.ajax({
           url: $("#login-form").attr('action'), //login.php
           data: $("#login-form :input").serializeArray(),
           method: $("#login-form").attr('method'), //post
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
           }
        }); 
    }
    else {
        $("#text-login-msg").text("Digite o Usuário e senha").css('color', 'red');
    }
    return false;   
});
```

Parece que o return false não está funcionando

Comment: Parece ser erros de javascript. acho que o `atr()` deve ser  `attr()`

Comment: mesmo depois de corrigir os erros de `atr()` continua dando os mesmos erros

Comment: Qual erro? vc precisa ligar o console de erros no navegador da um `F12` ai.

Comment: Consegui arrumar o erro, era algum erro de syntax no IF

Comment: com o jquery é `val()` no lugar de `value()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `return false;` só funciona em JavaScript inline no HTML.
Por exemplo (https://jsfiddle.net/Lho9vpe4/1/):

```
<form onsubmit="return enviar();">
```

Para parar dentro de um event handler, que é o teu caso, tens de usar o `.preventDefault();`.

No teu caso ficaria assim:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Contudo, se em nenhum caso vais enviar a `form` podias associar o auscultador de eventos a um botão ou outro elemento e chamar o ajax, sem ter de enviar a form. Sugestão apenas.

Comment: o que é "auscultador"? O.o

Comment: @rray _"event handler"_ -> http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/760/12